# Finding first partial derivatives of a function?

Tags: functions, derivatives

So I have this function $f(x,y,z)=x\sin(y-z).$

And I want to find :

the derivative with respect to $x$

the derivative with respect to $y$

the derivative with respect to $z .$

I think I should use the multivariable chain rule, but since I have dyscalculia I am not sure how to proceed adeguately .

I know that for the two variable chain rule,

$$\text{if} \quad f(x)=h(g(x)) \quad \text{then}\quad f'=h'(g(x))\cdot g'(x).$$ This formula for me is clear and I understand it well enough.

I have seen some formulas with three variables and they all seem very confusing for me so my question is,

could you please **help me with a formula to find the  derivative of a function composed of three variables with the same terms that i used in the equation above? meaning a formula with $h,g,$ possibly and  variable, maybe $i?$ Possibly followed with partial derivatives formula related to a $3$ variable composite function**

It would be really important for me if the formula could be in the same style of

$f(x)=h(g(x))$ then $f'=h'(g(x))·g'(x).\;$ (so a formula for composite function )

Thanks !!

Comment: You don't need the chain rule for this problem.  To take the partial derivative with respect to one of the variables, you treat the other two variables as if they were constants.  All three partials are very simple in this example.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!